# How do I order the menus added to org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, preference

org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages Extensions에
Added the following pages.

foo, bar, test

At this time, the menu appears in the order of bar, foot, and test, so it seems to be written in alphabetical order.

Can I specify this order display?

```
<page
   category="fooCategory"
   class="fooClass"
   id="fooId"
   name="foo">
</page>
<page
   category="barCategory"
   class="barClass"
   id="barId"
   name="bar">
</page>
<page
   category="testCategory"
   class="testClass"
   id="testId"
   name="test">
</page>
```

Comment: There isn't a straightforward way. In theory the `IContributionService` can be used to change the preference sort, but I have never seen it used.

Comment: What greg-449 says. The first page is _General_, all others are alphabetical ordered. The extension point does not provide an option to change this. See documentation: [_"The workbench adds several pages for setting the preferences of the platform. Pages registered through this extension will be added after them"_](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_preferencePages.html).